# Python - removing one instance of a value in two lists

Tags: python, list

Currently, I want to remove a value that is being looped through if it exists in both lists, as such:

```
for value in Word1:
    if value in Word2:
        Word1.remove(value)
        Word2.remove(value)
```

However, this code is returning `['a', 'b', 'b']` for the Word1: `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']` and Word2: `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` when I would expect it to return `['a', 'b']`. What is causing this issue? Pythontutor's visualisation doesn't seem to be helping me.

Comment: You are changing the lengths of the lists while iterating over them - this is a very bad move. Note that using `set` methods would simplify this significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You must not change a list, while iterating over it.
First, determine the elements, to be removed, then remove them:

```
to_be_removed = set(Word1).intersection(Word2)
Word1 = [w for w in Word1 if w not in to_be_removed]
Word2 = [w for w in Word2 if w not in to_be_removed]
```